# Get property value from property name which is stored as value in another node

Tags: neo4j

I have a query regarding neo4j cypher text

I have a property name of a node which is stored as value in another node.
Like a filter node has 'TV_TYPE' as the value stored in its name field

```
{
Name : 'TV_TYPE'
}
```

Now this TV_TYPE is the property of another node. How can I get the value of this property in this node

```
{
TV_TYPE : "LCD"
}
```

I need to get LCD. How can I get it using cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of Neo4j dynamic property access is not possible. Therefore you need to split up your operation into two Cypher statements:

1. the first fetches the property name `TV_TYPE`
2. the second Cypher statement is built up using string concatenation

Maybe you can solve the problem more elegantly by converting the property name into a node. You'd have `TV_TYPE` then available as first class citizen in your graph.

Comment: Hmm making separate node will lead to a lot of storage as there are lot of items with lot many filters. I will go with 2 queries for now. Thanks