# how a child node can inherit a property name without its value?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have a node called parent, In this node I have some properties like birthday, name, and children. The values of these properties are the translation of given words (name, children, birthday) in my language. How can I create a child in which the names of child property are translated values of my parent node?

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082521) but it is from 2014. I want to see of there is new feature that can solve my problem.

Example:

> Parent node: birthday = "test123"

What I want after creating the child node is:

> Child node: test123 = 2000

Comment: The answer you linked to is for *accessing* the value of a node property whose name is provided in another node. Your question seems to be about *creating* such child nodes, which is much more complex. You need to provide much more detail. For example: how do we know which parent node properties hold the name of a child property, how do we know the value of each child property, what other properties should a child have and where do their values come from, etc. Also, why do you want to use this indirect-naming approach? It requires a lot of complexity and is perhaps unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

First of all, I should state that this indirect-naming approach should be avoided if possible. It requires a lot of complexity and is perhaps unnecessary. As soon as you have information for the child, you should just immediately create the child instead of storing the child's info in the parent for additional processing later.

Also, the answer you linked to is for *accessing* the value of a node property whose name is provided in another node. Your question is about *creating* such child nodes, which is much more complex. You did not provide enough detail to know how you intended it to work. For example: how do we know which parent node properties hold the names of child properties, how do we know the value of each child property, what other properties should a child have and where do their values come from, etc?

But I will take a stab at proposing an approach, *assuming that you have a good reason for storing the child info in the parent for later processing*.

You can change the parent properties (like `birthday`) to have the desired child value (`2000`), and add a special parent property named, say, `propNameMap` whose value looks like this (and maps the parent property name to the child property name):

```
['birthday:test123', 'name:foo']
```

Then your code for generating a new Child node for a specific parent could look like the following query. It assumes you want to add a relationship as well. And it also assumes you want to remove `propNameMap` and the associated properties from the parent after creating the child.

```
MATCH (p:Parent {id: 123})
WHERE p.propNameMap IS NOT NULL
CREATE (p)-[:CHILD]->(c:Child)
WITH p, c
UNWIND p.propNameMap AS m
WITH p, c, SPLIT(m, ':') AS n
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(c, n[1], p[n[0]]) YIELD node AS ignored1
WITH p, c, COLLECT(n[0]) AS dropProps // Aggregation reduces # rows to 1
CALL apoc.create.removeProperties(p, dropProps+'propNameMap') YIELD node AS ignored2
RETURN p, c, SIZE(dropProps) AS nProps
```

Alternatively, if the parent node is no longer needed after creating the child node:

```
MATCH (p:Parent {id: 123})
CREATE (c:Child)
WITH p, c
UNWIND p.propNameMap AS m
WITH p, c, SPLIT(m, ':') AS n
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(c, n[1], p[n[0]]) YIELD node AS ignored
WITH p, c, COUNT(*) AS nProps // Aggregation reduces # rows to 1
DELETE p
RETURN c, nProps
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an APOC function that can set (or update) a property of a node.  Here is the documentation: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setProperty/

For your question, below is the cypher query for that:

```
//search for the parent node
MATCH (p:Parent {birthday: 'test123'}) 
//unwind is like a for loop and this will return all property keys of p
UNWIND keys(p) as key
//get the value of this property, for example 'test123'
WITH p[key] as newKey
//create the child node without any property and will update it later
CREATE (c:Child)
WITH c, newKey
//set the property of this node c using newKey and value: 2000
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(c, newKey, 2000)
//this apoc function will return the updated node c with new property c['test123']
YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

Here is the result:

```
{
  "identity": 1,
  "labels": [
    "Child"
  ],
  "properties": {
"test123": 2000
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer creates one child node per parent property. The question wants all properties in the same child.

Comment: i dont wanna update my whole database because of a name. what i want is instead of changing and updating all the nodes i change 1 node's property and then that change will be spread through all my nodes.